# Object lost its type and functions when passed by a web worker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-worker

I am using create-react-app and the lib d3-delaunay (https://github.com/d3/d3-delaunay) to generate a voronoi diagram. It is generated in a web worker managed with https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader. When passed to the main thread the generated object loses its attributes.
[image: js logs]

I cannot longer use the render fucntion I need to use so I tried to play with Object.assign and Object.create but I didn't succeed. What should I do?

Comment: You are supposed to pass data only. Moreover, you cannot access all APIs within web workers, so calling `render` could fail anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an object between threads, the [structured clone algorithm](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm) is used to make a copy of the object, which doesn't include functions. From that MDN link:

> ### Things that don't work with structured clone
>
> - [`Function`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) objects cannot be duplicated by the structured clone algorithm; attempting to throws a `DataCloneError` exception.
> - Cloning DOM nodes likewise throws a `DataCloneError` exception.
> - Certain object properties are not preserved:
>
>   - The `lastIndex` property of [`RegExp`](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) objects is not preserved.
>   - Property descriptors, setters, getters, and similar metadata-like features are not duplicated.
>             For example, if an object is marked readonly with a [property descriptor](/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor), it will be read/write in the duplicate, since that's the default.
>   - The prototype chain is not walked or duplicated.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Do you have a suggestion on how to recreate an object with the same data?